# How can i refresh view when i use removefromsuperview method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, page-refresh

I have two view controllers on iOS app.

The first view controller (A), store a table view with cells of data.
When i select a cell, i use the follow method for go to second view controller (B):

```
if (secondViewController == nil) {

     secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nibName" bundle:nil];
} 

 [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

When i am in the second view controller (B) and i want come back to first view controller (A) i use the method:

```
  [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

And then i come back to first view controller (A).

**The problem is:**

When i select a different cell in the first view controller (A) i go to the second view controller (B) but this time, with the same data of the previous cell. 
**The view controller doesnt refresh data automatically...**

I tried use the viewWillAppear, but it didnt work so i need a bit help. By the other hand, viewDidAppear doesnt work too of course.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's like that is because you create secondViewController just first time (lazy loading) after that you just add subview:

```
if (secondViewController == nil) {

secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nibName" bundle:nil];
}
```

You can sort it out by doing:

```
secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nibName" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

But where do you load the data to your subview. If you want to change the view depending on data you should do something like that:

```
if (secondViewController == nil) {

secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nibName" bundle:nil];
}
//Pass some data here
secondViewController.SOMEDATA = YOURDATA;
[self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

Comment: Your code works, thanks brother but i have a new question. The view controllers that u create all time, memory are released by themselves? i use arc, sorry for my english

Comment: In this scenario you shouldn't worry about memory. ARC take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[viewThatYouWantToRefresh setNeedsDisplay];
```

or if you need to update the data in the cells on the UITableView:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure I understood you correctly but I think you can change

```
if (secondViewController == nil) {
     secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nibName" bundle:nil];
}
```

to

```
secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nibName" bundle:nil];
```

So you will recreate SecondViewController each time you choose new cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this condition:
`if (secondViewController == nil)`

i.e no need to check if secondViewController is nil or not. The problem is you are creating secondViewController only once.